# What is purpose of zener diodes in this circuit?

Tags: i2c, zener

I am reading the I2C tutorial: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/i2c/all

Why wouldn't it work without the zener diodes? What functionality are they adding? They are just there to keep the voltage at a constant level when the logic is 1 right? When the logic is 0, the transistors are on, and the zeners do more or less nothing right?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no actual zener diodes in there; those represent the breakdown voltage of the [body diode in the MOSFETs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_MOSFET#Body_diode) themselves.